# PostgreSQL: output rows as list of comma-separated strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

On PostgreSQL 11, I’d like to output the rows of a table as a comma-separated list of strings:

```
id,info,name,message
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(t), ',', '')                                                                                                                          
FROM (                                                                      
    SELECT id, info, name, message
    FROM myschema.mytable
) t;
```

But this outputs:

```
(1,foo,bar,baz),(2,qux,zap,xen)
```

In constrast, the desired result should look like:

```
1,foo,bar,baz
2,qux,zap,xen
```

What would be the correct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(',', info, name, message)
FROM myschema.mytable;
```

No aggregation is necessary.  The values you want are all in one row.

You can, of course, include `id` in the string instead of as a separate column:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', id, info, name, message)
FROM myschema.mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.get_foo()
RETURNS SETOF text AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT COALESCE(array_to_string(array[id::text, info::text, name::text, message::text], ','), ''::text)
        FROM myschema.mytable;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then run:

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.get_foo();
```